# Prove that $\frac{(a+1)(a+2) ... (a+n)}{(b+1)(b+2)...(b+n)} \sim \frac{b!}{a!}n^{a-b}$.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

(Feller Volume 1, 2.12.21) Prove that for any positive integers $a$ and $b$ 
$$\frac{(a+1)(a+2) ... (a+n)}{(b+1)(b+2)...(b+n)} \sim \frac{b!}{a!}n^{a-b},$$
where $\sim$ here denotes that the ratio between two terms goes to unity as $n$ tends to infinity.

The question is equivalent to saying that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a! \frac{a+1}{n}...\frac{a+n}{n}}{b! \frac{b+1}{n}...\frac{b+n}{n}}.$$
This shows that the numerator and denominator both approaches to zero. There are too many $n$'s, so I am not sure if I can apply L'Hopital's rule. Can you give me suggestion how I can go further?

Comment: Perhaps take the natural logarithm of the expression in the limit and see what you get out of it? Maybe you can express the logarithm as its Taylor series? Some ideas although I dont know how useful they might be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion in question is equivalent to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(a+n)!n^b}{(b+n)!n^a}=1\;.\tag{1}$$

Without loss of generality suppose that $a\ge b$; then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(a+n)!n^b}{(b+n)!n^a}&=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{a-b}(b+n+k)}{n^{a-b}}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{a-b}\frac{n+b+k}n\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{a-b}\left(1+\frac{b+k}n\right)\;
\end{align*}$$

But

$$\left(1+\frac{b+1}n\right)^{a-b}\le\prod_{k=1}^{a-b}\left(1+\frac{b+k}n\right)\le\left(1+\frac{a+b}n\right)^{a-b}\;,$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{b+1}n\right)^{a-b}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a+b}n\right)^{a-b}=1\;,$$

establishing $(1)$.

Comment: Wow Amazing! thanks Prof Scott !

Answer (score 0):

Using Stirling approximation:

$$A = \frac{(a+1)(a+2) ... (a+n)}{(b+1)(b+2)...(b+n)} \Rightarrow \frac{a!}{b!}A = \frac{(a+n)!}{(b+n)!} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi(a+n)}(\frac{(a+n)}{e})^{a+n}}{\sqrt{2\pi(b+n)}(\frac{(b+n)}{e})^{b+n}}$$
$$
  =
\frac{\sqrt{(a+n)}}{\sqrt{(b+n)}}  \frac{(a+n)^{a+n}}{(b+n)^{b+n}} e^{b-a} $$

Now take a limit from the right side:

$$
B= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{(a+n)}}{\sqrt{(b+n)}}  \frac{(a+n)^{a+n}}{(b+n)^{b+n}} e^{b-a} = 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{(a+n)}}{\sqrt{(b+n)}} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(a+n)^{a+n}}{(b+n)^{b+n}} e^{b-a} =
$$

$$
e^{b-a} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(a+n)^{a+n}}{(b+n)^{b+n}} = 
e^{b-a} \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{a-b}\frac{(1+\frac{a}{n})^{a+n}}{(1+\frac{b}{n})^{b+n}}
$$

As we know $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{a}{n})^n = e^a$:
$$
B = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{a-b}
$$

It means when $n$ goes to $\infty$, the limits of $n^{a-b}$ is dominant. Hence for large $n$ we have:

$$
\frac{a!}{b!}A \sim n^{a-b} \Rightarrow A \sim \frac{b!}{a!}n^{a-b}
$$